# find the deepest LI in a lot of UL and LI using jquery

Tags: jquery, list, tree, html-lists

So there is this tree. It's compiled from a MySQL database using PHP.
The problem is that I want to find all the LIs who don't have a UL inside them and more LIs....

example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pet8Z.jpg

In the example I marked the LIs who should be selected with jquery, because they don't have any children and that's what I want.

Basically it's just a tree made from categories, but if the deepest category doesn't have any children it should be considered an item and I want jquery to find those items, which don't have any children.

This is the whole tree: http://jsfiddle.net/trueskillz/qnRpj/1/

I could do something like this(code down below) and check if it has children or not and then make it's background red(for example) and that's how I would find the 'items' and not 'categories', but there must be a easier way than this....

```
    $("#parttree ul").each(function(){
      $(this).find("li").each(function(){
          $(this).find("ul").each(function(){
              $(this).find("ul").each(function(){
                 $(this).css("background-color","red");
              });
          });
      });
    });
```

This is not a way a would like to find the items in this list... So I'm hoping there's a easier way...

Comment: So you want to find all leaf-nodes in a tree?

Comment: I think so... I want to find all LIs who don't have another UL in them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several options:

```
var $leaves = $('#parttree li').filter(function() {
    return !$(this).has('ul');
});

var $leaves = $('#parttree li:not(:has(ul))');

var $leaves = $('#parttree li').filter(":not(:has(ul))");

var $leaves = $('#parttree li').not(":has(ul)");
```

Comment: or `.filter(":not(:has(li))")` or `.not(":has(li)")` though, it should probably be `has(ul)`, not `li`

Comment: His answer works too. I just did `$(leaves).each(function()$(this).css("background-color","red");})` and everything that I needed went red. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DominykasTijūnaitis FYI, you don't need to use `each()` to set css like that, and you don't need to wrap a jquery object in `$()`. Using one of my examples, `$leaves.css('background-color', 'red');` should work.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks again! I kind of got a problem now... when I do `$leaves.append("part");` I get part written twice at each item, like so: http://clip2net.com/clip/m62718/1375897669-clip-25kb.png . Because I'm going to add input near each of them that's a huge problem... I could do check to see if a input already exists there, but yet again... there must a fix to this, right?

Comment: Can you post a simple jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Nevermind... There was a problem with jQuery 1.8.1 which I was using, updated to the newest one and it was fixed. (Noticed this because everything was working fine in jsfiddle). Thanks so much for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Your list structure is off a little bit. I would suggest trying to organize here: http://tools.arantius.com/tabifier

You also don't need jQuery to do this. You can use CSS.

```
#parttree li:last-child{
   background:red;}
```

But just deleting one of the ul's you had I was able to get a a close match. 
http://jsfiddle.net/gha8V/

I would just write out the ul's in a wordpress (or any wysiwyg) visual editor, click over to text, copy it, and then finally organize them html with the tabifier tool above.

Hope this helps.